# Resize Text to Fit DIV--with higher accuracy?

Tags: jquery, html, resize, font-size, autoresize

I'd like to fit a block of text into a div by changing the font size automatically.

I've been using this jQuery function,

```
$(function() {
    while( $('#fitin div').height() > $('#fitin').height() ) {
        $('#fitin div').css('font-size', (parseInt($('#fitin div').css('font-size')) - 1) + "px" );
    }
});
```

and it works well--except that the accuracy isn't high enough (it lowers the size by 1px every time; I need it to work with much smaller increments, such as .1mm). Am I missing something here?

Thanks--let me know if I haven't included enough info.

Comment: Your options would be to use a different unit like points or em that can take a fractional value and/or use justification.  I don't think you can see a difference specifying fractional pixel heights.  A tool, you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mvYpG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [*Pixel* on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel),

> In digital imaging, a pixel, pel, or picture element is a
>   physical point in a raster image, or the smallest addressable element
>   in an all points addressable display device; so **it is the smallest
>   controllable element of a picture represented on the screen**.

Then, you can't have more precision than a pixel.

Comment: My problem is that, for paragraphs 40 lines long or so, 1px ends up making a big difference over the entire text. Too big of a difference, in fact!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/). Have been using it for a while now and love it. Should solve the problem you are having.

Comment: Was that bit about "Oh, and don't you dare let us catch you using FitText on paragraph text. This is for gigantic display text only!" a joke, then?

Comment: Didn't know you intended to use it for paragraph text. This was not in your question. If anything FitText might be a good place to check out how they did it, and adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after days of trying, I've learned:

There is no way to change the font of a paragraph in a smaller increment than 1px PER LINE! Therefore there is no way to change the size of 40 lines, for example, in a smaller increment than 40px. Which is a problem. The only way I was able to do it, in the end, was by creating an image file of the block of text. Very annoying, if you want to change it at all, but it appears this is the only way possible.